# How to generate a P12 file, based on the key and PEM certificate?

Tags: gui, certificate, generator

I would like to generate a P12 file from the key and the PEM version of an iPhone developer certificate.
Is there a GUI based tool available for Windows XP?

Comment: GUI based, as in "please don't suggest `openssl pkcs12 -export`"?

Comment: Yes, because I don't get the openssl command line thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Windows GUI called **OpenSSLUI** built on top of OpenSSL, and it has an Util-tab where you can easily build a P12 file from your certificate files.

Download it from http://opensslui.sourceforge.net/